# How to detect rooting and how to request super access in android programatically

Tags: android

I need to know if the device is rooted or not and also I want to know how l can request Super User access. And again I want to know if I have been granted the access. 
Plz tell me if possible. I will be so grateful...

Comment: Download and use the "Root Checker" app from Play store to check the root access

Comment: No. I mean to say that I want to use those features in my application. I want to implement that progrmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static boolean isRooted() {
    boolean rooted = false;

    String binaryName = "su";

    String[] places = {"/sbin/", "/system/bin/", "/system/xbin/", "/data/local/xbin/",
            "/data/local/bin/", "/system/sd/xbin/", "/system/bin/failsafe/", "/data/local/"};

    for (String where : places) {
        if (new File(where + binaryName).exists()) {
            rooted = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return rooted;
}
```

Be careful on Emulator Running, it appears like Rooted device (You can see from the code above).

Comment: Ah... brother, to vote you up I neee 15 reputation. I am a new user. I have not enough reputation.If I had I would give you

Comment: Does it help for you?

Comment: Yeah I have understood what you did and how to detect rooting by getting exists of any folder above